# As one variable decreases another one increases

Tags: javascript

I have the following math problem inside JavaScript.

The problem: As x decreases, I need y to decrease proportionately to x as y approaches 0%.

And so when `x = 0%, y = 0%`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    x = 0.50;
    y = 0.30;
    if (x < 0.50){
        // set y here somehow to gradually increase
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do you want it to "gradually" increase?

Comment: Based on x. So x will reach 0 at the same time y reaches 100.

Comment: What about `x = 1 - y`?

Comment: You set `y = 0.30` when `x = 0.50`.  That's the place you want `y` to start increasing?

Comment: yes y=0.30 when x = 0.50

Comment: OK, I edited your question to reflect what you stated in my answer.  Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in `y` would be 0.6 times the change in `x` (assuming you want `y` to decrease linearly from 0.3 to 0.0 as `x` decreases from 0.5 to 0.0):

```
if (x < 0.50)
{
    y = 0.3 - 0.6*x;
}
```

Comment: I apologize I got the y direction wrong. I meant for it to decrease as well proportionately so both x and y should reach 0 at the same time. Should I post a separate one?

Comment: No worries.  Changed my answer to reflect this.